# Error Message When Importing Pandas in Jupyter Lab for New Environment

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I reinstalled anaconda navigator to my system and therefore created a new environment. When I imported pandas, the following error message comes up:

```
import pandas as pd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\finest\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     29 try:
---> 30     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
     31 except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover

~\anaconda3\envs\finest\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py in <module>
     12 
---> 13 from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
     14 from pandas._libs.tslibs import (

pandas\_libs\interval.pyx in init pandas._libs.interval()

~\anaconda3\envs\finest\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py in <module>
     29 from . import dtypes
---> 30 from .conversion import OutOfBoundsTimedelta, localize_pydatetime
     31 from .dtypes import Resolution

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion()

ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\anaconda3\envs\finest\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     36         "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     37         "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first."
---> 38     ) from e
     39 
     40 from pandas._config import (

ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: Access is denied. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

I do not experience this error message when I import pandas to the base environment.

Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Thanks

Comment: What. is your python and pandas version?

Comment: did you try to run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force"

Comment: 3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  8 2020, 13:18:14) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: No i did not run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force"